# Packingof Spheres in 3D

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, packing-problem

I am looking to find out the size of the largest sphere , that can fit in the voids created by packing spheres ( hcp) of radius R.

Comment: This question is not specifically related to Mathematica. Do you have some code that you have already begun working on?

Comment: Are you speaking of regular lattice sphere packings (and if so, which)? Especially if so, this is more a question about maths than use of Mathematica.

Comment: hcp == Hexagonal Close  Packing ....

Answer (score 1):

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres) under Positioning and Spacing it says there are two kinds of gaps.  One is tetrahedral with a distance from the center of the gap to the center of the sphere $\sqrt {\frac 32}$ for unit spheres, so a sphere of radius $ \sqrt {\frac 32}-1$ would fit.  The other is octahedral, and will take a sphere of radius $\sqrt 2 -1$